# help with script of logging

Tags: bash, scripts

I want to make a script that will store the output to a txt file , but the source of where I’m extracting it's changing name by one/ more character each day ( according to the calendar ).

How do I make a script that will help me each day search in next file in row or search it by date of creation ?

The command looks like this:

```
cat /etc/xxxx/logs/app_20151002.log | grep "IP address " | 
 awk '{print $10}' | uniq -c | sort -rnk1 | 
 awk '{print $2}' | tr "," " " | uniq -c | 
 grep -v "0.0.0.0" | >> /home/output.txt
```

Tomorrow the log file will be `app_20151003.log` and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
cat /etc/xxxx/logs/app_$(date +%Y%m%d).log | grep "IP address " | 
  awk '{print $10}' | uniq -c | sort -rnk1 | awk '{print $2}' | 
  tr "," " " | uniq -c | grep -v "0.0.0.0" | >> /home/output.txt
```

Explanation:

`date +%Y%m%d` returns the current date (as understood by the host's current time), in the format `YYYYMMDD` that you seem to want. The `$()` part is a useful bash macro that creates a sub-shell executes the commands between the parentheses and returns stdo into the original command.

Comment: does it matter that ubuntu returns date command in this order ? 
Fri Oct  2 09:24:42 CEST 2015 , meaning day-month-year ?

should i edit that ?

Comment: tried it , worked like a charm. big thx !!!